# perl utf8 encode from iso-8859-1 returns different result to javascript utf8 encode

Tags: javascript, perl, encoding, utf-8

In perl if I encode the following from iso-8859-1 to utf8.

```
(00000)   0a0b0111 666c6578 74696d65 05427351   ....flextime.BsQ
(00016)   f4aea370 00137469 6d657374 616d7009   ...p..timestamp.
(00032)   05010541 d3c8a8a2 40000004 aff01403   ...A....@.......
(00048)   61090301 090b0104 01040204 03040404   a...............
(00064)   0501                                  ..
```

This is the result:

```
(00000)   0a0b0111 666c6578 74696d65 05427351   ....flextime.BsQ
(00016)   c3b4c2ae c2a37000 1374696d 65737461   ......p..timesta
(00032)   6d700905 010541c3 93c388c2 a8c2a240   mp....A........@
(00048)   000004c2 afc3b014 03610903 01090b01   .........a......
(00064)   04010402 04030404 040501              ...........
```

If I decode the perl result using javascript, this is the what I get:

```
00000000: 00 0b 00 01 00 11 00 66 00 6c 00 65 00 78 00 74 00 69 00 6d 00 65 00 05 00 42 00 73 00 51 4b a3 |flextimeBsQ.|
00000016: 00 70 00 00 00 13 00 74 00 69 00 6d 00 65 00 73 00 74 00 61 00 6d 00 70 00 09 00 05 00 01 00 05 |ptimestamp.|
00000032: 00 41 04 c8 88 80 00 00 00 00 00 04 fc 14 00 03 00 61 00 09 00 03 00 01 00 09 00 0b 00 01 00 04 |A...a..|
00000048: 00 01 00 04 00 02 00 04 00 03 00 04 00 04 00 04 00 05 00 01 .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. |      |
```

Can anyone help me with this? The source is an AMF object sent from flash to a perl server which resends it to javascript. The way in which the data is sent (from flash to perl to javascript) does not change any of the data.

The code in perl is:

```
use Encoding;
from_to($out,"iso-8859-1","utf8",Encode::FB_WARN);
```

If I use the default utf8 encode in perl I get the same result.

This has been updated to include hex dump instead of binary.
I need a encode method in perl that will return the same result as javascript. Can be tested [using this page](http://coderstoolbox.net/string/).

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you encoding binary data? Encodings are meaningful for text strings.

Comment: You pasted [binary data](http://enwp.org/Action_Message_Format) and messed it up, it's not usable this way even if we do the substitution, unprintable characters such as NUL will be missing. [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9031995/edit) and post a hexdump instead.

Comment: Websockets (the javascript connection) can only transmit or recieve utf8 encoded strings. If you transmit anything else it will complain and disconnect.

Comment: If your trying to send binary data over a connection that doesn't support sending raw octets then your best bet is probably to use Base64 or similar to encode your data in a manner that is safe for transfer.

Answer (score 1):

Half an answer:

The three sequences again, in PERLQQ notation.

```
my $octets =
"\x0a\x0b\x01\x11\x66\x6c\x65\x78\x74\x69\x6d\x65\x05\x42\x73\x51".
"\xf4\xae\xa3\x70\x00\x13\x74\x69\x6d\x65\x73\x74\x61\x6d\x70\x09".
"\x05\x01\x05\x41\xd3\xc8\xa8\xa2\x40\x00\x00\x04\xaf\xf0\x14\x03".
"\x61\x09\x03\x01\x09\x0b\x01\x04\x01\x04\x02\x04\x03\x04\x04\x04".
"\x05\x01";

my $utf8_encoded_octets =
"\x0a\x0b\x01\x11\x66\x6c\x65\x78\x74\x69\x6d\x65\x05\x42\x73\x51".
"\xc3\xb4\xc2\xae\xc2\xa3\x70\x00\x13\x74\x69\x6d\x65\x73\x74\x61".
"\x6d\x70\x09\x05\x01\x05\x41\xc3\x93\xc3\x88\xc2\xa8\xc2\xa2\x40".
"\x00\x00\x04\xc2\xaf\xc3\xb0\x14\x03\x61\x09\x03\x01\x09\x0b\x01".
"\x04\x01\x04\x02\x04\x03\x04\x04\x04\x05\x01";

my $received =
"\x00\x0b\x00\x01\x00\x11\x00\x66\x00\x6c\x00\x65\x00\x78\x00\x74".
"\x00\x69\x00\x6d\x00\x65\x00\x05\x00\x42\x00\x73\x00\x51\x4b\xa3".
"\x00\x70\x00\x00\x00\x13\x00\x74\x00\x69\x00\x6d\x00\x65\x00\x73".
"\x00\x74\x00\x61\x00\x6d\x00\x70\x00\x09\x00\x05\x00\x01\x00\x05".
"\x00\x41\x04\xc8\x88\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\xfc\x14\x00\x03".
"\x00\x61\x00\x09\x00\x03\x00\x01\x00\x09\x00\x0b\x00\x01\x00\x04".
"\x00\x01\x00\x04\x00\x02\x00\x04\x00\x03\x00\x04\x00\x04\x00\x04".
"\x00\x05\x00\x01";
```

The third one is **UTF-16BE** encoded, the columns of `00` are the hint. Decoding results in an octet sequence similar to the first one, except the first octet `0a` is missing. The other differences are marked with `*` below, I have no explanation for those.

```
Test::HexDifferences::eq_or_dump_diff(
    $octets,
    "\x0a".encode('UTF-8', decode('UTF-16BE', $received))
);

+---+----------------------------+----------------------------+
| Ln|Got                         |Expected                    |
+---+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|  1|0000 : 0A 0B 01 11 : ....   |0000 : 0A 0B 01 11 : ....   |
|  2|0004 : 66 6C 65 78 : flex   |0004 : 66 6C 65 78 : flex   |
|  3|0008 : 74 69 6D 65 : time   |0008 : 74 69 6D 65 : time   |
|  4|000C : 05 42 73 51 : .BsQ   |000C : 05 42 73 51 : .BsQ   |
*  5|0010 : F4 AE A3 70 : ...p   |0010 : E4 AE A3 70 : ...p   *
|  6|0014 : 00 13 74 69 : ..ti   |0014 : 00 13 74 69 : ..ti   |
|  7|0018 : 6D 65 73 74 : mest   |0018 : 6D 65 73 74 : mest   |
|  8|001C : 61 6D 70 09 : amp.   |001C : 61 6D 70 09 : amp.   |
|  9|0020 : 05 01 05 41 : ...A   |0020 : 05 01 05 41 : ...A   |
* 10|0024 : D3 C8 A8 A2 : ....   |0024 : D3 88 E8 A2 : ....   *
* 11|0028 : 40 00 00 04 : @...   |0028 : 80 00 00 04 : ....   *
* 12|002C : AF F0 14 03 : ....   |002C : EF B0 94 03 : ....   *
| 13|0030 : 61 09 03 01 : a...   |0030 : 61 09 03 01 : a...   |
| 14|0034 : 09 0B 01 04 : ....   |0034 : 09 0B 01 04 : ....   |
| 15|0038 : 01 04 02 04 : ....   |0038 : 01 04 02 04 : ....   |
| 16|003C : 03 04 04 04 : ....   |003C : 03 04 04 04 : ....   |
| 17|0040 : 05 01       : ..     |0040 : 05 01       : ..     |
+---+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, it woulds seem now my problem is with the websocket and not perl.